# Whats the standard way to detect the window close event in the browser?

Tags: browser, chat, logout

Whats the standard way to detect the browser window close event in any standard browser? By standard I mean something that sites like Google or Facebook implement when the "keep me signed in" checkbox is unchecked. I have an interactive website in place where theres an Instant Messaging module and I need to inform the other user that the partner has logged out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The keep me signed in links are managed via cookies and cookie timeout lengths.

One approach to doing something like this is to have the browser make an async ajax call every (1 minute) to your server so you know they are still logged in. If you dont receive one of these calls within say 90 seconds you can say they are logged out.

This approach would also catch cases where for example their connection went or their computer crashed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have heard of the AJAX calls. Can you show me the code? I have used something like:
    window.setInterval(myfunc,2000);
    function myfunc(){
    $.ajax(//AJAX call here..);
    }

    Is this right?